# Windows 8.1 not connecting to Wifi from PSK

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I have a 64 byte hex PSK for a Wifi network, but when I enter it in Windows 8.1 it refuses to connect: if I enter it from the connection dialog it says it is incorrect, but if I try to enter it with a new manual connection it just silently fails. I have double-header the key is correct, and I am able to connect with the same key in Linux (where it is set as the psk in wpa_supplicant.conf)

When manually entering the key, Windows claims I can enter the key as "64 characters using digits 0-9 and letters A-F" which made me think maybe I had to use upper-case A-F instead of the lower case I was using, but that did not fix the problem.

Can Windows really use this format or is there perhaps some incompatibility between the format used by Linux and Windows?

Comment: I have indeed used WPA+PSK in Windows before.

Comment: @Ramhound I am not given the choice of WPA-PSK, only WP2-Personal, Enterprise, etc.

Comment: Then your hardware does not support it.  WPA is broken anyways the encryption is trivial to brute force.